# How to combine host network with the default network in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm building the docker-compose service that includes two containers. One of those containers (**node**) is designed to support an auto-discovery mechanism and needs to be a part of the host LAN (as I need multicast UDP packages to be handled by the LAN router, not the built-in docker router).

While the "network_mode: host" in docker-compose.yml perfectly does the trick, I need this service to be also available to a second container (**qtcore**) by its hostname via the default docker-compose network (like that: http://node:37326). And that doesn't seem to be possible with the network_mode set to "host".

My docker-compose.yml currently looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    qtcore:
        image: yansidorovtesseris/qtcore
        build: .
        container_name: qtcore
        depends_on:
            - node
        env_file: defaults.env
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"

    node:
        image: yansidorovtesseris/komodo
        container_name: node
        env_file: node.env
        ports:
            - "37326:37326"
            - "1900:1900"
        network_mode: host
        volumes:
            - $HOME/node_state:/komodo/.komodo/$AC_NAME
```

I've tried to use the sample from the docker-compose docs (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#host-or-none)
to connect the host network as an external network. With the thought to add both host and default networks to a service.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    node:
        ...
        networks:
            hostnet: {}
        ...
networks:
    hostnet:
        external: true
        name: host
```

But all I get when I try to run the docker-compose is the following error:
`ERROR: for node  network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks`

Comment: Maybe you need to separate these containers and just the first need to use host network. Then the second container can access to first through extra_hosts config.

Comment: That's an option, yes. Though I'd like to make it as easy as possible and avoid the need of manually mapping the hostname to an IP address

Comment: Possible to create two network. One with `network_mode: "host"` and another with `network_mode: "bridge"`?  
The first container use both of them and the second only the bridge network. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode

Comment: @hNczy
That was my initial intention. But the "network_mode" property can be used with the service unit only, not the network adapter. Therefore only one value could be set per service: it's either "host" or "bridge"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alright, it seems to me that it's impossible to configure service to use both "host" and "bridge" options simultaneously. Would be glad if someone points out the opposite, though.

I've come up with a simple workaround to allow services to operate as a one docker-compose unit in a host LAN and yet use the "extra_hosts" (suggested by hNczy) for the hostname lookup.

It isn't ideal and might not fit for every scenario, but it does the trick for me.

Basically, two services are both using the "network_mode: host" right now, and the "extra_hosts" of a "qtcore" service is supplied with the "node" name bound to 127.0.0.1.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    qtcore:
        image: yansidorovtesseris/qtcore
        build: .
        container_name: qtcore
        depends_on:
            - node
        env_file: defaults.env
        network_mode: host
        extra_hosts:
            - "node:127.0.0.1"
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"

    node:
        image: yansidorovtesseris/komodo
        container_name: node
        env_file: node.env
        ports:
            - "37326:37326"
            - "1900:1900"
        network_mode: host
        volumes:
            - $HOME/node_state:/komodo/.komodo/$AC_NAME
```

Comment: In case, you don't want to expose the ports from the komodo container to the outside world you could change the `ports:` declaration to only forward to `127.0.0.1` and remove the `network_mode: host`, i.e.
```yaml
    komodo:
        ...
        ports:
            - "127.0.0.1:37326:37326"
            - "127.0.0.1:1900:1900"
        volumes:
            ...
```

Answer (score 3):

@Dima

> Sadly host.docker.internal does not work on Linux.

I thought that, too! Until today. Just found this and it works for me. On linux it did never before. The host-gateway will resolve to the same IP than default gateway in docker-container. If you attach a network it will be the bridge-ip xxx.xxx.xxx.1.
But it will not be the host-ip.

Try this:

```
services:
  your-container:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

I'm struggling around with different problem. I need to attach default bridge of docker and at the same time a second service needs to access the one having default-bridge.

Obviously docker-compose denies that. Attaching default bridge manually while a docker-compose "internal" network is attached works fine. So technically it works, but somehow it is "blocked" by docker-compose I think.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.docker.com/network/host/, it says where you declare network mode = host then port mappings are ignored.

Solution: **Use host.docker.internal:portNumber to use/connect to host ports from a container which is in bridged network mode/dafault mode.**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  qtcore:
    image: yansidorovtesseris/qtcore
    build: .
    container_name: qtcore
    env_file: defaults.env
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
  node:
    image: yansidorovtesseris/komodo
    container_name: node
    env_file: node.env
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - '$HOME/node_state:/komodo/.komodo/$AC_NAME'
```

Now when in host mode komodo can use any ports which it is designed to work.
Now in qtcore whenever you want to connect to host port use host.docker.internal.
ex: **host.docker.internal:37326 OR host.docker.internal:1900** , whatever port komodo is using. Never used komodo so can't write exact port.

Comment: Sadly `host.docker.internal` does not work on Linux.