# How to alias sibling container in docker when running with network_mode host

Tags: networking, docker-compose, home-assistant

I have two docker containers running from a compose file as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  homeassistant:
    user: 999:994
    container_name: homeassistant
    image: "ghcr.io/home-assistant/home-assistant:stable"
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /run/dbus:/run/dbus:ro
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - mosquitto
      
  mosquitto:
    user: 999:994
    container_name: mosquitto
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
      - 9001:9001 
    volumes:
      - /opt/mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
      - /opt/mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - /opt/mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

I would like to access the mosquitto container from the homeassistant container using the alias 'mosquitto', so that within the homeassitant container I can reach the other container with, eg: `ping mosquitto`.

This doesn't work as the homeassistant container is using "network_mode: host" - if I remove that, it works fine.

How can I configure the networking so that the homeassistant container can still use "network_mode: host", but I can still reach the other container using the alias "mosquitto"?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've found in two questions on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58236867/how-to-combine-host-network-with-the-default-network-in-docker-compose) and [devops.stackexchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/connect-docker-container-to-both-host-and-internal-bridge-network), it seems I can get things to work by using the extra_hosts option to add mosquitto as an alias to localhost for the homeassistant container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  homeassistant:
    user: 999:994
    container_name: homeassistant
    image: "ghcr.io/home-assistant/home-assistant:stable"
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /run/dbus:/run/dbus:ro
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - mosquitto:127.0.0.1
    depends_on:
      - mosquitto
      
  mosquitto:
    user: 999:994
    container_name: mosquitto
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
      - 9001:9001 
    volumes:
      - /opt/mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
      - /opt/mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - /opt/mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

This acheives what I want, although I'm not sure if it's the most elegant way of doing things.